# cant update context state when using hooks with a complex object to set providers value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I call `toggleFilterSidebar` it should toggle the state of filterSidebarIsOpen from false to true and vice versa but onClick nothing happens, but when I pass the Provider value directly as an object it works.

Why does this work?

1).

```
return <FilterSidebarContext.Provider value={{
    toggleFilterSidebar,
    filterSidebarIsOpen,
    filters,
  }}>{children}</FilterSidebarContext.Provider>;
```

and this doesnt

2).

```
  const [value] = useState({
    toggleFilterSidebar,
    filterSidebarIsOpen,
    filters,
  });

  return <FilterSidebarContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</FilterSidebarContext.Provider>;
```

**My Code**

FilterSidebar.context.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const FilterSidebarContext = React.createContext({});

export const FilterSidebarProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [filterSidebarIsOpen, setFilterSidebarIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const toggleFilterSidebar = () => setFilterSidebarIsOpen(!filterSidebarIsOpen);
  const [filters] = useState({ regions: [] });

  const [value] = useState({
    toggleFilterSidebar,
    filterSidebarIsOpen,
    filters,
  });

  return <FilterSidebarContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</FilterSidebarContext.Provider>;
};

export const FilterSidebarConsumer = FilterSidebarContext.Consumer;
export default FilterSidebarContext;
```

FilterButton.js

```
const FilterButton = ({ className, getTotalActiveFilters }) => {
  const { toggleFilterSidebar, filterSidebarIsOpen } = useContext(FilterSidebarContext);

  return <Button className={cx({ [active]: filterSidebarIsOpen })} onClick={toggleFilterSidebar} />;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code:

```
  const [value] = useState({
    toggleFilterSidebar,
    filterSidebarIsOpen,
    filters,
  });
```

you are providing `useState` with an initial value which is only used when the component is first mounted. It will not be possible for `value` to ever change since you aren't even creating a variable for the setter (e.g. `const [value, setValue] = useState(...)`).

I assume you are using `useState` here to try to avoid a new object being created with each render and thus forcing a re-render of everything dependent on the context even if it didn't change. The appropriate hook to use for this purpose is [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

```
  const value = useMemo(()=>({
    toggleFilterSidebar,
    filterSidebarIsOpen,
    filters
  })[filterSidebarIsOpen]);
```

I've only put `filterSidebarIsOpen` into the dependencies array, because with your current code it is the only one of the three that can change (`toggleFilterSidebar` is a state setter which won't change, `filters` doesn't currently have a setter so it can't change).

Answer (score 0):

useState expects a function to set the value after useState initially does, so if value represents state, setValue would represent setState...

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
```

then use setValue to change it

```
onClick={() => setValue(newValue)}
```